# Kafka connect transforms (SMT) - Help to resolve the use case

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a use case where i would like to map my source table key field to target table reference field using kafka source or sink connector.

I am new to this forum, pleas let me know if i am missing to add any information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use: `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value` Transformation

Configuration section with Transformation should looks like follow:

```js
{
    ...
    "transforms": "RenameField",
    "transforms.RenameField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
    "transforms.RenameField.renames": "SRC_ID:SRC_REF_ID"
    ...
}
```

If your column `SRC_ID` is of type Int you might also need casting to `String`. For that you can use: `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast`

More detail about default Transformation can be found: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response - wardziniak!!!.. yes, its working as expected. i dropped the target table and re-created with SRC_REF_ID column with NUMBER data type and used ReplaceField transforamation as you suggested and its working as expected. Great!... My problem is resolved but I do have other question. Incase my use case is still to retain all my sources fields in target table but would want to add new field in target table which should copy the value copied from SRC_ID field to SRC_REF_ID field, how would i do this?  Appreciate your response!..

Comment: @JamesMark, default transformations don't support cloning/copying field values. You only can change the name, but can't create new field with same value. For that you have to create your own transformation, sample can be found: https://github.com/wardziniak/kafka-war-transform

Comment: Thank you for the response wardziniak!.. I understand the limitation of the SMT and to write the custom transformation. I looked at your code but looks like it has been written on scala which i didnt know.

Comment: Hi wardziniak, yes you answered already to my questions and it resolved my problems as well.  I have marked as answered. since i am new to this forum, please let me know if i haven't done properly.

Comment: @wardziniak-how can we mention the topic name in source connector? I have created the topic with 3 partition and i want to mention the existing topic in source connector and see by default to which partition the message will be sent. then 
as you suggested in other post, i want to override the partition assignment using custom logic. you can see my other post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188508/custom-partition-assignment-in-kafka-jdbc-connector

Comment: @JamesMark, Jdbc connector builds topic name based on prefix property (and if it is table mode it additionally adds table name). If it is not enough for you, you could use  Confluent Transform: ExtractTopic(https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#extracttopic)

Comment: @Wardziniak-:Thanks for the response. I able to use the existing topic name using the topic.prefix attribute itself. actually, i manually created the topic "test_topic1_SRC_EVENT_NEW" with 3 partitions and providing the below attributes in connector configuration. messages are being sent to all the 3 partition base on some default algorithm.         "table.whitelist": "SRC_EVENT_NEW",
        "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
        "topic.prefix": "test_topic1_".   even if i am not creating topic, its automatically creating in this name. i didnt set any property in server.properties