# Custom partition assignment in Kafka JDBC connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a use case where i need to write a custom logic to assign the partition based on certain key parameters from the message. I did some research on this and found that kafka transformation supports to override some methods in Transformation  interface but i was unable to do some example code in git hub or somewhere. can someone please share the sample code or git hub link to do the custom partition assignment in kafka JDBC source connector?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Can you post some code showing your attempt?

Comment: Hi Kieveli, Thanks for the response. I did this custom partition in custom producer and its working fine but i would like to do the same in kafka source connector. since i could not find some sample, i haven't tried yet.

Comment: I only asked because this site works great when you have example code showing the problem you're having rather than a general request for code.  Adding your example and rephrasing the question might get you help faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kafka Connect** to assigning partitions by default uses: `DefaultPartitioner` (`org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner`)

If you need to override default one with some custom, it is possible, but you have to remember, that overriding applies to **all Source Connectors**.
To do that you have to set `producer.partitioner.class` property, ex `producer.partitioner.class=com.example.CustomPartitioner`.
Additionally you have to copy jar with your partitioner to directory with Kafka Connect libraries.

**Transformation way:**

Setting the partition is also possible in Transformation, but it is not proper approach.
From `Transformation` you don't have access to topic metadata, that are crucial for assigning partitions.

If anyway you would like to set partitions for your records, code should look like this:

```java
public class AddPartition <R extends ConnectRecord<R>> implements Transformation<R> {

    public static final ConfigDef CONFIG_DEF = new ConfigDef();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> props) {
        final SimpleConfig config = new SimpleConfig(CONFIG_DEF, props);
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(R record) {
        return record.newRecord(record.topic(), calculatePartition(record), record.keySchema(), record.key(), record.valueSchema(), record.value(), record.timestamp());
    }

    private Integer calculatePartition(R record) {
        // Partitions calcuation based on record information
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigDef config() {
        return CONFIG_DEF;
    }
}
```

Comment: @wardziniak- I tried the custom partition as per your suggestion but i could not override the partition assignment. i have posted the connector and custom partition details in the original post. could you please check and let me know if i am missing anything here. Thank you for continues response!.

Comment: @JamesMark, `producer.partitioner.class` is global setting for all connectors. You have to set it in kafka connect global properties, ex in file `connect-standalone.properties` (for standalone) or `connect-distributed.properties`

Comment: @wardziniak-Great & Thank you so much!.. Its working as per the solution you have provided and added the below transformation in the connector!                    
        "transforms": "cusPart",
     "transforms.cusPart.type": "com.anthem.kafkaconnect.AddPartition"